# Seleccionar campos selectOneMenu jsf al enviar datos a una pagina de edición

Tags: jsf, select

estoy trabajando con jsf. La pregunta que planteó es como seleccionar(selected) los campos selectOneMenus que forman parte de un registro. En mi caso tengo 3 selectOneMenu y ninguno se muestra como debería. Pues al enviar los datos para edición, no muestra seleccionado el valor que le corresponde sino el primer item. En el caso que envíe el post, me pediría seleccionarlos, cosa que no debe pasar.

Lo que estoy haciendo es enviar los datos para edición, seleccionando un registro de la tabla que contiene todos los registro de base de datos. Ya en la vista edición, sucede que los selectOneMenu no muestran seleccionados los valores correspondientes. ¿Hay algún modo de hacer esto? Estuve buscando un poco por ahí y no encontré mas que preguntas de combos anidados.

```
/*Buscando registro*/
public void load(){
    medicamento = dao.buscar(id);
}

/*Cargando datos del registro*/
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{medicamentoManaged.id}"></f:viewParam>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{medicamentoManaged.load}" />
</f:metadata>

/*Data para cboEspecie*/
public List<Especie> getListadoE() {
    listadoE = dao.listarEspecies();
    return listadoE;
}

/*select one menu cboEspecie*/
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{medicamentoManaged.medicamento.especie.especieId}" id="cboEspecie" styleClass="form-control">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione Especie" itemValue="0"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{medicamentoManaged.listadoE}" var="e"
    itemLabel="#{e.descripcion}" itemValue="#{e.especieId}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Y se ve así

[image: Seleccionar selectonenu en vista de edicion]

Comment: Quita la imagen y sube el código, tanto html como Java, para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Entra a load? Sería interesante que colgaras la clase Java entera.

Comment: Deberías cambiar el método getListadoE() de forma que sólo devolviera listadoE, sin llamar a dao.listarEspecies(), y realizar esa llamada al dao en la carga de la pantalla. La manera en que lo tienes puede producir problemas (aparte de no cumplir ciertas convenciones).

Comment: Con el listener carga los datos, el problema es que no selecciona los campos que deberia. Lo que quiero es editar no solo mostrar, y para eso son necesarios los selectonemenu, y si por defecto me aparecen sin seleccionar, obligado tendria que elegir una nueva especie, laboratorio, cosa que solo deberia hacer cuando quiera editar esos campos. En el getListadoE() estoy cargando los datos con el dao desde la bd, asi que si no le paso el daoListarEspecies() estaria nulo. -[shoy777](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54218/shoy777)

Comment: Ese no es el lugar indicado para la llamada al dao, haz la prueba de quitarlo y ponerlo en el load() junto con la otra llamada, y deja el getListadoE() como te digo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo solucione, como estaba utilizando inner join, me falto, seleccionar los id de las foraneas. De todos modos gracias por tu ayuda -[shoy777](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54218/shoy777)